# Python BeautifulSoup - Possible to get X number of links from page?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is it somehow possible to only get lets say the first 10 links from a page with BeautifulSoup?

Something like;

```
for tag in soupan.findAll('a') in range(10):
```

Have tried to Google it and cant seem to find how to achieve that. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work:

```
for tag in soupan.findAll('a')[:10]:
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Beautiful Soup's `find` methods take a [SQL-style "limit" argument](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-limit-argument):

```
for tag in soupan.find_all('a', limit=10):
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `for tag in soupan.findAll('a')[:10]:` work?

the other option is:

```
for i, tag in enumerate(soupan.findAll('a')):
    if i >= 10:
        break
```